# PHP get database data into HTML table

Tags: php, html

I want to put my database data into HTML table and its not so easy as it seems, Look at my photographs and code to get better understanding on what my problem is

My Result:

[image]

Desired Result:

[image]

Basically i want to separate the results as the red line indicates so each item becomes seperate.

PHP code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products"); ?>


<table id='display'>


    <?php
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
            {
    ?>
        <tr><td><?php echo "<img src=$rows[$product_image] height='200px' width='200px'>" ?></td></tr>

        <tr>
        <td><b><?php echo "$rows[$product_name]" ?></td>
        <td><b><?php echo "Avalible: $rows[$product_qua]" ?></td>
        <td><b><?php echo "Price: £ $rows[$product_price]" ?></td>
        <td><b><?php echo "Description: $rows[$product_des]" ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><strong><p>Please Login To purchase this item </p></strong><a href="login.php">Login</a></td>
        </tr>

        <?php
            }
        ?>

</table>
```

CSS code:

```
table#display{
    float:left;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:10px;

}
table#display td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:0 8px;

}
table#display tr{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:0 8px;

}
```

Comment: You could create a new table for each result and set "margin-bottom" in the CSS to make the tables appear separate.

Comment: And a decent template system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:
PHP Code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products"); ?>

<?php
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
?>
<table class='display'>
    <tr><td><?php echo "<img src=$rows[$product_image] height='200px' width='200px'>" ?></td></tr>

    <tr>
    <td><b><?php echo "$rows[$product_name]" ?></td>
    <td><b><?php echo "Avalible: $rows[$product_qua]" ?></td>
    <td><b><?php echo "Price: £ $rows[$product_price]" ?></td>
    <td><b><?php echo "Description: $rows[$product_des]" ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><strong><p>Please Login To purchase this item </p></strong><a href="login.php">Login</a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

The CSS:

```
table.display{
    float:left;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;    
}
```

Comment: ur suggested solution works just the way i wanted it to be many thx